# Why I'm not getting full text at output?

Tags: python

I tried to run this code but I'm not getting full name printed in the output. Can anyone tell why?

here is code:

```py
import sys                          # import sys module to send arguments to our application
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets         # import QtWidgets to create Application
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

def window():                       # create a function to launch desktop Application
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = QMainWindow()
    
    win.setGeometry(800, 200, 900, 700)
    win.setWindowTitle("TTL Framework")
    win.setWindowIcon(QIcon('icon.jpg'))
    
    lbl_name = QtWidgets.QLabel(win)
    lbl_name.setText('Enter Name :')
    lbl_name.move(50,50)
    
    lbl_surname = QtWidgets.QLabel(win)
    lbl_surname.setText('Enter Surname :')
    lbl_surname.move(50,90)
    
    
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
    
    
window()
```

[image]

Comment: [Please do not post images of text output.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/15168)  What does C have to do with this Python code?

Comment: I'm getting full text when I run your code in my machine.

Comment: Adding unrelated tags is considered spamming and is likely to attract downvotes.

Comment: give the label a background color, you don't have a size large enough

Comment: @Bhargav, Do you add any lib for running code or directly its giving o/p?